# Unable to use extern and static storage-class specifiers together

Tags: c, static, extern

In [C99](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29#C99) 6.7.1 it says

> At most, one storage-class specifier may be given in the declaration
>   specifiers in a declaration

I know `extern` and `static` are both storage class specifiers but `extern` basically states to the compiler that the variable is declared elsewhere and worry about it later. `extern` and `static` to me are **NOT** mutually exclusive. It is very well possible that something could be `extern` and `static`.

Why can't we use `extern` and `static` together? Is there a good reason other than the standard simply says, no?

Comment: Your question makes more sense if "to me are" is replaced with "to me aren't". Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, `static` means `Internal Linkage`, `extern` means `External Linkage`.

`Internal Linkage` refers to everything only in scope of a Translation unit.

`External Linkage` refers to things that exist beyond a particular translation unit. In other words, accessable through the whole program.

So both are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score -2):

"Static" outside all blocks means "internal linkage", "extern" means external linkage.
What should static extern mean? Internal external linkage???

Comment: Pen pineapple apple pen